# PHP saving previous file upload information with a users account

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, session

I'm looking for a way to save a list of what a user uploads to my site (i.e images files) with php sessions. I want to be able to have a user view their uploaded files in a list once they login on the page I have already set for file uploads. Is this possible to do with just php sessions and not with a database?

Comment: Sure, but that data won't be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but images association isn't persistent. There is just a limited time you're able to handle session and there are a lot of users using more than once computer. I wouldn't recommend this. I would recommend database, which is the best way to do so

Comment: Okay. Do you know of any examples like this that use a database?